# Owner side with JoinColumns annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have the following scenario:
I'm having troubles figuring out what the owner side is and why ?
Please can you help ?

```
public class Basket
{

...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="BASKET", referencedColumnName="ID")})   
    public Set<Product> getProductList() {
        return this.productList;
    }
}

public class Product
{

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="BASKET", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    public Basket getBasket() {
        return this.basket;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why?  `@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="BASKET", referencedColumnName="ID")})` 
 just `@JoinColumn(name="BASKET", referencedColumnName="ID")`

Comment: I don't know I'm trying to figure it oit as well..I inherited this code form others

Answer (score 0):

Basket is the "One" side of the relationship and there are many products identified as Baskets.  So the "one" is usually the parent code and the child records reference the parent.  Usually the easiest way to understand these is to look at the database foreign key constraint (hopefully there is one) that connects the backing tables.

Answer (score 0):

One client has One basket and One basket has One owner, so:

`class Owner` has basket in relation `@OneToOne`.

One basket has many products, so:

`class Basket` has List of products in relation `@OneToMany`.

Many Products has One basket so:

`class Product` has relation in `@ManyToOne`.

Answer (score 0):

The extract from the [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) might help you to understand the issue:

> ## 2.10.2Bidirectional ManyToOne / OneToMany Relationships
>
> Assuming that:
>
> ```
>     Entity A references a single instance of Entity B.
>     Entity B references a collection of Entity A[21].
> ```
>
> Entity A must be the owner of the relationship.
>
> The following mapping defaults apply:
>
> ```
> Entity A is mapped to a table named A.
> Entity B is mapped to a table named B.
> ```
>
> Table A contains a foreign key to table B. The foreign key column name is formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the relationship property or field of entity A; "_"; the name of the primary key column in table B. The foreign key column has the same type as the
>   primary key of table B.

And in section 11.1.21 the following is stated:

> If there is more than one join column, a JoinColumn annotation must be specified for each join column using the JoinColumns annotation. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such JoinColumn annotation.

In your case, there is only one join column. So you don't need to the `@JoinColumns` annotation. Just use`@JoinColumn`. The `@JoinColumn` annotation is used always on the **owning side of the relationship**, that is the `@ManyToOne` side in this case.

Comment: thanks, but I think that using those annotations like in my example the one tomany is the owner side, I would like to understand why ?

Comment: The OneToMany side cannot be the owner of the relationship. The owner is always the one where you put your foreign key in database terms. You cannot put the foreign key on the `One` side; if you do you will have multiple values for the same record in the database. I am not trying to convince you; I am just telling you how the framework handles the relationship and how the database should be designed if it is supposed to comply with the relational database paradigm.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think you are right http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: I have seen what you have linked; but the above quote is not mine; it is the official JPA specification. How Hibernate implements it is not my problem. And I believe that is the right way to go. `This solution is not optimized and will produce some additional UPDATE statements.` what I read in section 2.2.5.3.1 of the document you linked.

Comment: If your intention is to understand the concept behind the mappings you might also want to read [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations). It has lots of examples which show how to map correctly.